# Why do I get timeout problems with Thunderbird and Sendgrid?

Tags: thunderbird, plugins, smtp, queue

I am helping my friends sending a newsletter (1000 recipients) using **Thunderbird 7.0.1** and the **Mail Merge** plugin.

For the SMTP provider we are using **Sendgrid**.

Mail Merge plugin nicely splits the messages into individual ones and starts sending them, but they are having **timeout problems** with the SMTP server.

Do you have any idea why is this happening? Is Thunderbird trying to send all the mails in it's outbox at once? I hope it is not the case. **Is there any way to control** how is Thunderbird processing it's queue? Is there any plugin for Thunderbird to control this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was with Sendgrid indeed, and the solution was to use their **X-SMTPAPI header** 
instead of just sending messages with Bcc: or sending individual messages from Thunderbird. Using their own header, the processing of emails worked perfectly and it was enought to send one message only.

Comment: I use a mail spooler/queue, and sendgrid's SMTP service doesn't connect about 70% of the time.  For me it will retry every 15 min, but it is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue sounds to me like it is on the SMTP service side, not Thunderbird.

Sendgrid should have no problem with 1000 emails at once through their SMTP service.

I use [Elastic Email](http://elasticemail.com) SMTP Relay and have had no issues.  Maybe try another service like Elastic to test where your problem lies.  Elastic lets you send 100/day up to 1000 emails for free, so it would be a cheap way to test this.

Comment: My problem was with Sendgrid indeed, and the solution was to use their X-SMTPAPI header instead of just sending messages with Bcc: or sending individual messages from Thunderbird. Using their own header, the processing of emails worked perfectly and it was enought to send one message only.